R count exact counts of substring within string
I have a column of text entries. I have recreated a short version of it below:
String_ID=c("ID1","ID2")
String_text=c("This is the first body of text.The movie is about a boy who loves ships. He builds his own ship. But the ship sinks.",
          "This is the second body of text.")
df=data.frame(String_ID,String_text)

I am trying to count the number of times "he" appears in each line of the String text row. However, the issue is that when I try the following:
library(stringr) 
df$Count <- str_count(df$String_text,'he')

I get the following:

It appears that the str_count function is counting the words "The" as an instance of "he". Is there a function or way to avoid this?
I have also tried the gregexpr function but get the same error.
df$Count_alt=lengths(gregexpr('he', df$String_text)) 

The correct counts I would expect is:

Can someone help identify how I would go about trying to fix this issue?

If you need case insensitive whole-word matching, try df$Count <- str_count(df$String_text,'(?i)\\bhe\\b')
